# How can I upload my Dockerfile to Docker Hub when pushing an image through automated builds?

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, dockerhub

I setup docker automated build via Github and I can build an image successfully from a Dockerfile in my GitHub repository

I have followed the thread [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-upload-my-dockerfile-to-docker-hub/6563/3) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/)

According to the documentation, if I do my build via an automated build connected to Github, all I need is to have my Dockerfile present and it will be added.

The builds succeeds, so the automation process works. 
I can even see the Readme from GitHub in the registry. But for some reason, I can't see my Dockerfile in Docker hub.

Here is [an example Github repo](https://github.com/jungopro/vsts-agent-infrastructure) and here is the [repository in Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jungopro/azure-devops-agent)

Is there any more configuration necessary to get the Dockerfile to docker hub?

Answer (score 0):

welcome Jungo!

### TL;DR

You can learn more information about [why](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-view-the-dockerfile-in-an-image/5687/3) on the Docker forum.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. However, the "auto-build" passes and I don't think I'm falling into any of the categories mentioned in the post...